# Why do I have to manually install basic usb drivers everytime I switch a devices USB port in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, drivers, device-manager

When I say basic USB devices, I am talking about your standard keyboard, mouse, thumb drive.  Nothing special or exotic.

They will appear in Device Manager with an !, error code 1, saying that they are not configured correctly.  If I right click and update the driver it installs fine.

Any suggestions or ideas?

UPDATE:
-Checked power management settings for the USB Root Hub, and that did not fix the issue.
-The only USB devices on this are mouse, keyboard, and a thumb drive. No other devices (i.e. cellular phones)
-One person mentioned that it could be a bad windows install.  Aside from a complete reinstall, any suggestions on the fix?

Comment: Do you have cell phone software installed?

Comment: You have to do this because your installation is screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this issue is due to your  power options. The Windows Power Management Option can turn off USB devices.

- Open Device Manager,
- Select a USB device such as the keyboard
- Right click and select properties.
- Navigate to the Power Management tab.
- Make sure the computer cannot turn off the device to save power.

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  That isn't it though - Power Management isn't an option for the keyboard and mouse, and after I disabled it on the USB Root Hub the issue was still present.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your the USB driver for the onboard controller is bad or the wrong version.  Try downloading the latest drivers from your computer's vendor.